# How to configure phpunit located in vendor/bin directory?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to set the database for the tests I'm going to run but I have one problem:

- I can't run phpunit because I have an older version.

I've already read all posts related to upgrade phpunit in a global context but I've failed doing that. I tried everything and I just couldn't upgrade phpunit globally so I started to use **vendor/bin/phpunit** instead and everything works fine. Now that led me to a second problem:

- How can I set the database where I am going to run my tests?

I know I need to set all the information about the database in the phpunit.xml file but the one that is in the base path works only for the global phpunit version. So where can I set the database information for the **vendor/bin** phunit version?

Comment: If you're in the root of your project (where your `phpunit.xml` and `vendor/`-folder are), it should work if you just run: `./vendor/bin/phpunit`. (if you're on either linux or mac).

Comment: Thank you for your comment but my question is not about how to make phpunit work. I want to run a test and I need to create some records and erase them after the test ends. The problem is that I need to set where this tests are going to be run. But as I'm using vendor/bin/phpunit I don't know where to set that information.

Comment: Then your question is pretty unclear about what the actual issue is. But what you can do is to set `<phpunit bootstrap="path/to/your/bootstrap/file.php">`. That's a file that will be loaded before the tests so you can set up a mock-database class instead and configure what you want. You can also set some env-variables, just like @Harmoud shows in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

phpunit.xml works for both local and global phpunit installation. You don't need a global phpunit. Just run your test using `./vendor/bin/phpunit`.

For the database configuration add the following to your phpunit.xml:

```
    <!-- To use sqlite in memory (Faster)
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>

    <!-- To use Mysql -->
    <!--<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="databse_test"/>-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just tried what you suggested but when I run the tests all database tables are removed (I used the sqlite way) so I guess phunit is not reading the phpunit.xml. Also, the colors are set to true but when I run the test is not displaying any.

Comment: So, what I'm still trying to figure out is where is the xml file that I need to change to affect the vendor/bin/phpunit command

Answer (score 3):

As others have said `./vendor/bin/phpunit` should read the `phpunit.xml` file if you running things from your app root path. To help with testing you can explicitly say what config file you need, like:

`vendor/bin/phpunit -c ./phpunit.xml`

but if the file is in the current directory you in its not needed, perhaps just double check that.